# Is there any way to refresh the page from webpart when user clicks on save as draft in sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs

We have implemented some webpart where filtering is happening when user select some value from the dropdown and its working fine but when we click on save as draft at that time old filter value is coming up instead of selected filter value and after that if we refresh we are able to get the new filter value
How to overcome this issue?
Do we have any method to call refersh the webpart when someone clicks on the save as draft?

[image]

[image]

[image]